# How to properly use variable in a query? postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

```
$result = pg_query(Postgres::getInstance(), "SELECT 
date_start, 
date_end, 
cnt_hands, 
cnt_hands_won, 
amt_won, 
id_session,
id_player,
amt_won  
FROM 
cash_table_session_summary 
WHERE 
date_start = '2016-04-27 07:20:47'");
```

This works perfectly.

```
echo $sessionStart;
$result = pg_query(Postgres::getInstance(), "SELECT 
date_start, 
date_end, 
cnt_hands, 
cnt_hands_won, 
amt_won, 
id_session,
id_player,
amt_won  
FROM 
cash_table_session_summary 
WHERE 
date_start = $sessionStart");
```

This throws this:

> 2016-04-27 07:20:47 Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax
>   error at or near "07" LINE 13: ... date_start = 2016-04-27 07:20:47 ^
>   in /home/haris/public_html/project/DAL_General.php on line 102

Is colon a problem? Do I need to escape it somehow? If so, how? I've google but found nothing about escaping colons.

Comment: Use it as `date_start = '$sessionStart'"` inside single quotes

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to php, and it didn't even occured to me, that that is possible. Can you make an answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date must be inside quotes. You need to change

```
FROM 
cash_table_session_summary 
WHERE 
date_start = $sessionStart
```

To

```
FROM 
cash_table_session_summary 
WHERE 
date_start = '$sessionStart'// add quotes here
```

For more understand about quotes check [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was learning database work, but you need the query to be made in `""`'s - Then when referencing a variable or data you need to put it in `'`'s, example:

```
$test_query = type_of_connection_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '1'");
```

That would not work like:

```
$text_query = type_of_connection_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1");
```

And of course there are some times when you don't need quotes, like referencing `LIMIT`'s

```
$text_query = type_of_connection_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '1' LIMIT 1");
```